# I can't use custom activity transition while applying intent flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT

Tags: android

I'm new to Android programming. I don't know much about it.

I've made an app with two activities, 'A' and 'B'. 'A' is the main activity. A contains a listview. When I'm clicking on an item in the listview, it opens activity B(used intent without any flag). In the onBack pressed event of activity B, I used intent(without any flag) to return to activity A. That works fine.I want custom slide transition. So I used the code
'''overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left,R.anim.slide_out_right);'''
after the start intent.
That also works fine.

In the activity A, I was using method parcelable to save the position of listview. But when I'm using intent to go to activity A, the position of listview changes to 0.

When I used intent flag, FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT(for restoring an activity), the slide transition isn't working.

So my question is:
Is there any way to set slide transition without intent?

Comment: You no need any intent to back to the first activity by default. When you start a new activity, previous activity was added to backstack, and his state was saved. All what you need is just tap back button. Make sure you don't use `finish()` method, when you start second activity, because this close an activity, and removes it from backstack.